# Show a popup as soon as the user enters into the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a spring MVC application And we are using Spring Security.

Now I have a requirement that as soon I enter into the application, a pop up should be displayed. So the application might enter directly into home page or to his profile page or to any other flow in the application. But I need to show the pop up irrespective of where the user enters.

How do I achieve this using Spring security or any other alternative please?

I have tried:
config.xml:

```
<bean id="popUpFilter" class="myPackage.security.popUpClass" />
 <security:http entry-point-ref="myAppAuthEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
.............
    <security:custom-filter after="LOGIN_FILTER" ref="popUpFilter"/>
</security:http>
```

And My Code:

```
public class popUpClass implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(popUpClass.class);

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    //do some logic here if you want something to be done whenever
    //the user successfully logs in.
    log.debug("Entered into customfilter");

    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
    User user =  SecurityClass.getUserDetails();
    session.setAttribute("id", user.ID());
    session.setAttribute("state", user.State());

    //set our response to OK status
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    //since we have created our custom success handler, its up to us to where
    //we will redirect the user after successfully login
    httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("home");
}
```

}

NOTE: Popup should appear only once after the user log in.

Comment: You should be doing this on the client side, either by window.onLoad or if using jQuery $.ready......Spring security kicks in when a request reaches the server.

Comment: I agree with @kmansoor - additionally, you can set a cookie on the client after showing the pop up, the presence of which you can use to determine whether or not to show the pop up each time a certain browser accesses the site. If a per-browser pop up is inappropriate, record the shown pop up in your user database and query each time to see if you need to show the pop up.

Comment: @JonSampson i have edited the code. But i am not able to enter into the filter class. Can you please let m enow where it went wrong.